# Change the order of bars in a grouped barplot with hvplot/holoviews

Tags: python, bokeh, holoviews, hvplot, holoviz

I try to create a grouped bar plot but can't figure out how to influence the order of the barplot.

Given these example data:

```py
import pandas as pd
import hvplot.pandas

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "lu": [200, 100, 10], 
    "le": [220, 80, 130], 
    "la": [60, 20, 15], 
    "group": [1, 2, 2],
})
df = df.groupby("group").sum()
```

I'd like to create a horizontal grouped bar plot showing the two groups 1 and 2 with all three columns. The columns should appear in the order of "le", "la" and "lu".

Naturally I'd try this with Hvplot:

```
df.hvplot.barh(x = "group", y = ["le", "la", "lu"])
```

With that I get the result below:
[image: grouped barplot in wrong order hvplot]

Hvplot does not seem to care about the order I add the columns (calling `df.hvplot.barh(x = "group", y = ["lu", "le", "la"])` doesn't change anything. Nor does Hvplot seem to care about the original order in the dataframe.

Are there any options to influence the order of the bars?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has just been **fixed in HoloViews 1.13**.

You can sort your barplot just like you wanted:

```py
df.hvplot.barh(x="group", y=["lu", "la", "le"])
```

As I write this, HoloViews 1.13 is not officially available yet, but you can install it through:

> pip install git+https://github.com/holoviz/holoviews.git

**If you want even more control over the order, you can use .redim.values() on your grouped_barplot:**

```
group_specific_order = [2, 1]
variable_specific_order = ['lu', 'la', 'le']

# Note that group and Variable are the variable names of your dimensions here
# when you use this on a different grouped barchart, then please change to the 
# names of your own dimensions.
your_grouped_barplot.redim.values(
    group=group_specific_order, 
    Variable=variable_specific_order,
)
```

Comment: Than I'll flag this answer as correct - though right know I'm happy with the workaround

Answer (score 3):

For normal bar charts, you can just order your data in the way you want it to be plotted. 
**However, for grouped bar charts you can't set the order yet.**
But development of this feature is on the way and probably available in one of the next releases: https://github.com/holoviz/holoviews/issues/3799

**Current solutions with Hvplot 0.5.2 and Holoviews 1.12:**

**1)** If you're using a Bokeh backend, you can **use keyword hooks**:

```
from itertools import product

# define hook function to set order on bokeh plot
def set_grouped_barplot_order(plot, element):
    # define you categorical ordering in a list of tuples
    factors = product(['2', '1'], ['le', 'la', 'lu'])

    # since you're using horizontal bar set order on y_range.factors
    # if you would have had a normal (vertical) barplot you would use x_range.factors
    plot.state.y_range.factors = [*factors]

# create plot    
group = df.groupby("group").sum()
group_plot = group.hvplot.barh(
    x="group",
    y=["le", "la", "lu"],
    padding=0.05,
)

# apply your special ordering function
group_plot.opts(hooks=[set_grouped_barplot_order], backend='bokeh')
```

Hooks allow you to apply specific bokeh settings to your plots. You don't need hooks very often, but they are very handy in this case.
Documentation:
http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Customizing_Plots.html#Plot-hooks
https://holoviews.org/FAQ.html


**2)** **Another solution** would be to convert your Holoviews plot to an actual Bokeh plot and then set the ordering:

```
from itertools import product
import holoviews as hv
from bokeh.plotting import show

# create plot
group = df.groupby("group").sum()
group_plot = group.hvplot.barh(
    x="group",
    y=["le", "la", "lu"],
    padding=0.05,
)

# render your holoviews plot as a bokeh plot
my_bokeh_plot = hv.render(group_plot, backend='bokeh')

# set the custom ordering on your bokeh plot
factors = product(['2', '1'], ['le', 'la', 'lu'])
my_bokeh_plot.y_range.factors = [*factors]

show(my_bokeh_plot)
```

Personally I prefer the first solution because it stays within Holoviews.

**Resulting plot:**
[image: customized categorical axes in grouped barcharts using keyword hooks]