# How to hide/remove the axis alone without removing the axis labels in holoviews

Tags: plot, holoviews

When I  add in`... .opts(title="Graph",ylabel="Count",width=400,axiswise=True,xaxis='bare')`
`xasis='bare'` or `xaxis=none` it makes the whole axis disappear along with the labels in `holoviews`. How do I only remove only the axis while displaying the `axis` labels?
Here the label is given as `ylabel` as axis is inverted. `ylabel` sets label for `xaxis`

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64297423/how-to-set-order-of-bars-according-to-order-index-of-dataframe-in-holoviews/64315986#64315986) for sample graph code

Also is there a way to give a main title  for side-by-side plots asides the individual plot titles in holoviews.

Comment: What do you mean by removing the axis? Do you mean removing the tick marks, while retaining the text labels? Or removing the axis line?  Or...?

Comment: Removing `axis` line as well as `tick marks` while retaining lables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to dive into bokeh for this. You can do this either with a hook, or rendering the bokeh object and working with it directly:

Hook approach:

```
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension("bokeh")

def hook(plot, element):
    plot.state.xaxis.major_tick_line_color = None        # turn off x-axis major ticks
    plot.state.xaxis.minor_tick_line_color = None        # turn off x-axis minor ticks
    plot.state.xaxis.major_label_text_font_size = '0pt'  # turn off x-axis tick labels


df = pd.DataFrame({
    "set": list("ABABCCAD"),
    "flag": list("YYNNNYNY"),
    "id": list("DEFGHIJK"),
})

df = df.groupby(["set", "flag"])["id"].count().reset_index()
count_bars = hv.Bars(df, kdims=["set","flag"], vdims="id")

plot = (count_bars
        .opts(hooks=[hook], title="IDs",invert_axes=True, width=500, padding=2)
        .redim.values(flag=["Y", "N"]) # Inverting the axes flips this order. This produces N, Y vertically
        .sort("set", reverse=True)
       )
```

Rendering the bokeh object and working with it:

```
from bokeh.io import show
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension("bokeh")
    
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "set": list("ABABCCAD"),
    "flag": list("YYNNNYNY"),
    "id": list("DEFGHIJK"),
})

df = df.groupby(["set", "flag"])["id"].count().reset_index()
count_bars = hv.Bars(df, kdims=["set","flag"], vdims="id")

plot = (count_bars
        .opts(title="IDs",invert_axes=True, width=500, padding=2)
        .redim.values(flag=["Y", "N"]) # Inverting the axes flips this order. This produces N, Y vertically
        .sort("set", reverse=True)
       )

bokeh_figure = hv.render(plot)
bokeh_figure.xaxis.major_tick_line_color = None        # turn off x-axis major ticks
bokeh_figure.xaxis.minor_tick_line_color = None        # turn off x-axis minor ticks
bokeh_figure.xaxis.major_label_text_font_size = '0pt'  # turn off x-axis tick labels

show(bokeh_figure)
```

Both methods produce this plot:
[image]

Comment: Looks good! I think the OP wanted to keep the labels, so the lines with `major_label_text_font_size = '0pt'` would be omitted here.